# How to append api url to Base URL in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hi i am trying to append  url  to include an id to the end of it.

below is what i have written

```
@DELETE("/customer-management/id/{id}")
    fun deletUser(@Path("id") id: String): Single<Response<ResponseBody>>
```

This doesnt work and instead tries to make a request to this url:

```
http://localhost/customer-manegement/id/%2Fcustomer-management%2id%2F9a4615d5-aaa9-4a56-ff43-fb4ef7a54f96",
```

It should be

```
http://localhost/customer-manegement/id/2F9a4615d5-aaa9-4a56-ff43-fb4ef7a54f96
```

The docs from retrofits Path indicates it should work as i expected:

Simple example:

```
* 
 * GET("/image/{id}")
 * Call ;ResponseBody; example(@Path("id") int id);
 *
 * Calling with {@code foo.example(1)} yields {@code /image/1}.
```

Comment: I would double check that you are calling `deleteUser` with the right `id`

Comment: i am calling the delete user, i see it in my logs, thats how i am able to rerieve the wrong http request url

Comment: along with it, print the value of id

Comment: the value of id is 2F9a4615d5-aaa9-4a56-ff43-fb4ef7a54f96 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `http://localhost/customer-manegement/id/%2Fcustomer-management%2id%2F9a4615d5-aaa9-4a56-ff43-fb4ef7a54f96"`

It seems that your base url is `http://localhost/customer-manegement/id/`
So your request should look like

```
@DELETE("/{id}")
fun deletUser(@Path("id") id: String): Single<Response<ResponseBody>>
```